# Lost skeleton dresser key

Tags: lock

I bought a dresser from someone and they said they lost the key.  What is the best way to open it?  It would be ok to force it open but don’t have any idea how to do it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens if you poke the pin with something?

Comment: These are usually simple enough that they can be picked with an adequately strong L shaped metal tool of suitable dimensions.  Do you have a metal coat hanger on hand?  The original is often just a tube with a rectangular flag and no significant keying.  If it's a really nice dresser it could be harder to pick.

Comment: A sardine tin key was a good substitute...

Comment: you can buy those kind of keys on amazon.

Comment: @nick012000 - almost certainly nothing; the pin is just there for the hollow tube of the key to rotate on, and to limit (slightly) the sort of alternate tools you can slip in to pick the lock.

Comment: If all else fails, using a drift and hammer, a sharp tap or two will detach the body of the lock from inside. Obviously there'll be some repair work later. As said, if all else fails...

Answer (score 5):

If you can't pick it yourself, or find a key that works, make an appointment if needed & carry it to a locksmith with a shop (avoiding the usually expensive part of having the locksmith come to you) and they can almost certainly do it.

The usual latch arrangement (a latch bolt going straight up into a hole/catch in the frame, from the key area) will cause significant visible damage if you force it open.